# Regex remove everything after : (including :)

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey everyone I have a string like: `Foundation: 100`

I want to use JS regex to remove everything after `:` including (:)

thanks for any help!

Comment: indexOf and substr should work fine.

Comment: Just in case if you are interested how the 2 methods compare speedvise: http://jsperf.com/get-part-before

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```js
var text = "Foundation: 100";
text = text.replace(/:.*$/, "");
console.log(text);
```

Comment: just curious, how would I apply this logic to remove everything BEFORE the :

Answer (score 5):

For your example you could call `.split(":")` on your string and then select the first array element using `"[0]"`

```
var whole_text = "Foundation: 100";
var wanted_text = whole_text.split(":")[0]
console.log(wanted_text)
```